# What is the difference between cell, membrane and animal based assay?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

I am reading a review about MRP1, discussing it's ability to extrude different compounds from cell interior. When describing the different experiments conducted to observe the MRP1's reaction to different modulators, the writers refer to cell based, membrane based an animal based assays. 
What is the difference between these three assays? What would be the purpose of choosing each of them for a specific test?
Thanks alot,
Yaron.

Comment: Can you perhaps link the review you are reading?

Comment: Sure,
http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-pharmtox-011613-135959